# Android - retrieve the device-appropriate drawable folder as a string

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Is it possible to retrieve the correct drawable folder name as a String using Android?

For example, I would like, as a string:

```
String drawableFolder = someFunction.getFolder();
Log.i("", drawableFolder);
```

....to output:

```
XXDPI
```

.

Usage case: I'm downloading images from a remote URL and would like a mechanism to retrieve a device-appropriate image.  It occurred to me I could prepend the URL with the correct name, e.g. http://static.images.server.com/XXDPI_image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the following through device density

```
int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

switch(density)
{
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    Log.d(TAG, "LDPI");
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
     Log.d(TAG, "MDPI");
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    Log.d(TAG, "HDPI");
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
     Log.d(TAG, "XHDPI");
    break;
}
```

Comment: OK, but is there a way to obtain the strings programatically rather than hard-coding them into the app?

Comment: you can get this `int` `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:`

Comment: OK if it's not possible to get the actual corresponding string representing the resource folder ('MDPI', 'HDPI', etc) from the system then I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: You can search and satisfy yourself, AFAIK `HDPI` etc cannot be returned, because it does not work like that. If you know `R.java` then you probably understand it better

Comment: I've never looked into `R.java` but I think I get the gist of what you're saying; essentially the resources get compiled into the app and the runtime has no knowledge of the various folder names.  Thanks for the best available answer.

Comment: Yup you got the essence . :)