# Which folder will the element receive the params? (Android)

Tags: android, screen, resolution

My avd is mdpi and I have an element that is defined in `values`, `values-hdpi`, `values-large-hdpi`, `values-xlarge` folders. When I run the project, from which folder will the compiler get the element references. Note: this element is not defined in `Activity.java`.

Comment: You can also find which drawble is in use http://stackoverflow.com/a/29769616/1061944

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Seems like question is not about drawables

Comment: if you read, `from which folder will the compiler get the element` and it will defininately get folder, if it is mdpi folder will be values-mdpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the folder values-hdpi will be to hdpi and above
- the folder values-xhdpi will be to xhdpi and above

as mdpi is less than hdpi so it will take the values from the folder which is least below it in you case it is values which is applicable to all